# QML slider tickmark with text at start and end

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

[image]

How to achieve something like this.
Should the text thin and thick must be outside slider as labels or can they be part of tickmarks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be easily done with styles. I advice you to look at QML controls/styles source in `$QTHOME/qml/QtQuick/Controls[/Styles/Base]` to have an understanding of default styles of QML controls.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4


Window {
    id: rootWindow
    visible: true
    height: 800
    width: 800

    Rectangle {
        width: 350
        height: 100
        color: "#555"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Slider {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            minimumValue: 1
            maximumValue: 5
            stepSize: 1
            tickmarksEnabled: true
            width: 300
            style: SliderStyle {
                handle: Rectangle {
                    width: 18
                    height: 30
                    border.width: 2
                    border.color: "#555"
                    color: "#CCC"
                    radius: 5
                }
                groove: Rectangle {
                    height: 15
                    width: parent.width
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    color: "#CCC"
                }
                tickmarks: Repeater {
                    id: repeater
                    model: control.stepSize > 0 ? 1 + (control.maximumValue - control.minimumValue) / control.stepSize : 0

                    Item {
                        Text {
                            y: repeater.height + 5
                            width : repeater.width / repeater.count
                            x: width * index
                            height: 30
                            color: "#CCC"
                            font.pixelSize: 20
                            text: getText()
                            horizontalAlignment: getAlign()

                            function getText() {
                                if(index === 0) return "THIN"
                                else if(index === repeater.count - 1) return "THICK"
                                else return "";
                            }
                            function getAlign() {
                                if(index === "0") return Text.AlignLeft
                                else if(index === repeater.count - 1) return Text.AlignRight
                                else return Text.AlignHCenter;
                            }
                        }
                        Rectangle {
                            color: "#CCC"
                            width: 2 ; height: 5
                            y: repeater.height
                            x: styleData.handleWidth / 2 + index * ((repeater.width - styleData.handleWidth) / (repeater.count-1))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exampe is full of excessive and worthless code but that's good for understanding.

Comment: I have not tested this code, which certainly doesn't look worthless and exactly what i was looking for. tickmarksEnabled:true plays a major role here which is not mentioned anywhere in qt docs. ne ways Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like they can be a part of the tick marks, but you can easily achieve this with separate text labels:

```
 Slider {
    id: slide
    width: 200
  }

  Text {
    text: "THIN"
    anchors.top: slide.bottom
    anchors.left: slide.left
  }
  Text {
    text: "THICK"
    anchors.top: slide.bottom
    anchors.right: slide.right
  }
```